# How to Generate Date

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a form and on a button click I automatically generate a date exactly a year in the future. I would like to know how to make sure that this date is not on a public holiday or on a weekend. Any help please ?

I would like to store the value of the date inside a variable in order to just place it inside the `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DueDate",___________)`

Comment: The weekend part is easy, because your `DateTime` value has a `DayOfWeek` property.  As for the public holiday, there's nothing built in to do that, so you're just going to have to compare the date to a list of relevant public holidays dates.

Comment: So you are saying that if I use DayOfWeek then it will automatically ignore weekends and only consider the days Mon - Friday ? @ jmcilhinney

Comment: No, you will have to choose what days to ignore.  DayOfWeek will just let you know what day of the week a date is on.

Comment: When someone refers you to a type or member, don;t just guess what it does or ask them what it does.  Go and look at what it does for yourself.  Then apply some logic to how using it would be useful in your scenario.  Logic works the same way in programming as it does any place else.  If someone told you they were planning to go somewhere on a particular date and you didn't want them to go on a weekend, would just finding out what day of the week that date was on do anything automatically?  Why should it here then?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own logic for this. It's quite simple. Create a method that check if the date is a weekday or a holiday. But you have to hard-code the holidays since they differ per country/continent/culture etc.

```
public bool IsWeekday(DateTime date)
{
    int dayOfWeek = (int)date.DayOfWeek;

    //week starts on sunday
    if (dayOfWeek == 0 || dayOfWeek == 6)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}


public bool IsHoliday(DateTime date)
{
    int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

    //define your holidays here, they differ between cultures and continents etc
    List<DateTime> holidays = new List<DateTime>()
    {
        new DateTime(currentYear, 1, 1), //new years day
        new DateTime(currentYear, 1, 9), //for testing
        new DateTime(currentYear, 4, 27), //kings day
        new DateTime(currentYear, 6, 21), //longest day of the year
        new DateTime(currentYear, 12, 25), //christmas
        new DateTime(currentYear, 12, 26) //christmas
    };

    //check the date against the list of holidays
    if (holidays.Any(x => x == date.Date))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now you can check if it works.

```
//get a monday
DateTime monday = new DateTime(2019, 1, 7);

//loop all days of the week
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    DateTime nextDay = monday.AddDays(i);
    Label1.Text += string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2}<br>", nextDay.ToLongDateString(), IsWeekday(nextDay), IsHoliday(nextDay));
}
```

Result of the above loop

```
maandag 7 januari 2019 - True - False
dinsdag 8 januari 2019 - True - False
woensdag 9 januari 2019 - True - True
donderdag 10 januari 2019 - True - False
vrijdag 11 januari 2019 - True - False
zaterdag 12 januari 2019 - False - False
zondag 13 januari 2019 - False - False
```

Comment: This is a vb.net question.